# Need to add new data manually to Google Forms response sheet already in reverse chronological order

Tags: google-forms

I have a Google Form, and I have re-organized the answers, in a separate tab where they're being captured on a Google Sheet, so that they are in reverse chronological order.

I need to manually add more data for each response in the columns to the right. However, when a new response comes, the old responses shift down but the cells where I am manually adding more info do not. So, I have to manually insert cells every time there is a new response. Since this is a shared project, I need the cells to shift down automatically.